# SphinxQL and SPH_MATCH_ANY

Tags: sphinx

I am using SphinxQL to query Sphinxsearch engine. I want to simulate the SPH_MATCH_ANY which is implemented in the php API like this :

```
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$cl->Query("test query", "index");
```

=> search for docs matching with "test" OR "query"

So, I have written a function (php) to replace spaces and other special chars with pipes (|) in order to use it with SphinxQL :

```
function formatQuery($str) {
   return trim(preg_replace('/[^-_\'a-z0-9]+/', '|', $str), ' |');
}

$str = "test query";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('" . addslashes(formatQuery($str)) . "')";
```

=> SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('test|query');

The problem is, for some characters like - (minus), it can break the query, example :

```
$str = "i-phone is great";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('" . addslashes(formatQuery($str)) . "')";
```

=> SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('i-phone|is|great')

=> ok

```
$str = "i - phone is great";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('" . addslashes(formatQuery($str)) . "')";
```

=> SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('i|-|phone|is|great')

=> broken query because of "|-|"

Do you know a better way to make SphinxQL queries work in SPH_MATCH_ANY mode? or a better regexp to make it works for all cases?

I know I could use a more restrictive regexp like this:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '|', $str)
```

but it would split strings like "i-phone is great" in 'i|phone|is|great' and I don't want that...

Thank you,
Nico

Comment: why don't you use the Sphinx API [EscapeString](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-escapestring) method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to use quorom

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('\"" . addslashes($str) . "\"/1')";
```

you will need to add - to your charset_table tho, so it becomes part of a word.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is

```
$query = preg_replace('/(\w+?)[-\'](\w+?)/','$1~$2',$query);
$query = preg_replace('/[^\w\~]+/','|',$query);
$query = preg_replace('/(\w+~\w[\w~]*)/e','"\"".str_replace("~"," ","$1")."\""',$query);
```

To turn it into a phrase.

Comment: Nice trick. For those that use Unicode strings (with accented characters like "éèàù" for example), you can use the "u" modifier in the regexp:
`$query = preg_replace('/(\w+?)[-\'](\w+?)/u','$1~$2',$query);`
`$query = preg_replace('/[^\w\~]+/u','|',$query);`
`$query = preg_replace('/(\w+~\w[\w~]*)/ue','"\"".str_replace("~"," ","$1")."\""',$query);`